# Change entity attributes after inserting

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I would like to create an entity named `Price` represented by `DataPrice` using Core Data. I would like to edit the entity after creating it. This is how I do it.

```
@interface DataPrice : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *ron95;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *ron92;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *dieselNormal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *dieselSpecial;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *postDate;

+ (instancetype)insertDataPriceWithPrice:(Price*)price
                  inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;

+ (instancetype)fetchDataPriceInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;

+ (Price*)fetchPriceInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;

@end



+ (instancetype)insertDataPriceWithPrice:(Price*)price
             inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    DataPrice* dataPrice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:self.entityName
                                               inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [dataPrice setId:price.id];
    dataPrice.ron95 = price.ron95;
    dataPrice.ron92 = price.ron92;
    dataPrice.dieselNormal = price.dieselNormal;
    dataPrice.dieselSpecial = price.dieselSpecial;
    dataPrice.postDate = price.postDate;

    return dataPrice;
}
```

This is causing thread problems. Am I doing it correctly?

Edit: Error information from XCode

[image: code]

[image: error]

Comment: What exactly does not work? Where is the problem?

Comment: Actually, Your question is not clear. What is the problem you are facing?. Detailed Question helps easy understanding

Comment: As I mentioned at your last Q, you should read the introductory tutorials about Core Data.

Comment: I've attached XCode's output to help clarify. It looks as if editing the entity's attribute isn't allowed after inserting it.

Comment: It looks like the line `[dataPrice setId:price.id];` is the problem. EIther Core Data doesn't allow editing `id` after inserting or it's failing for some other reasons such as a type mismatch.

Comment: may be price is destroyed already before you call insertdata... method. Check the price in debug.

Comment: The code that follows it is working.

Comment: The code is working after I have changed id to type `NSNumber` like this: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *id;`

Comment: Replace your property name from `id` to any other name in your `Price` and `DataPrice`, because `id` is type in Objective-C. You can use `id` as variable name in Swift.

Comment: Look at Mundi's answer. He is right. You can't use `id` as property for a class, because `id` is reserved as type in Objective-C. Try using different variable name instead of `id` in your classes like `Price` and `DataPrice`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using an attribute name that is an expression that is reserved in Objective-C. Try refactoring by replacing `id` with something like `idNumber`.